# How to expose an existing wsdl in Switchyard

Tags: soap, wsdl

I have a wsdl and I want to expose it as a service with SOAP binding in SwitchYard. Can any one tell how do expose a wsdl in SwitchYard.

Also I want to know how to expose multiple WSDLs in switchyard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to expose a wsdl in SwitchYard, you can follow below steps :

1) You need to drag the Service icon from Palett.

2) Select Interface Type as WSDL.

3) Browse to the location of wsdl and click Finish. That's it.

4) For exposing the service with SOAP binding, drag the SOAP icon from Palett to the service icon.

You may refer the below link on how to expose multiple wsdls :

https://developer.jboss.org/message/910909#910909